# How to round up number to nearest 100/1000 depending on number, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, max, rounding

I have a number that can be in the 2 digits, like 67, 24, 82, or in the 3 digits, like 556, 955, 865, or 4 digits and so on. How can I round up the number to the nearest n+1 digits depending on the number?

Example:

```
roundup(87) => 100,
roundup(776) => 1000,
roudnup(2333) => 10000
```

and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to the closest 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984578/rounding-to-the-closest-100)

Comment: what is the desired behavior for 10 itself? 10 or 100? The answers below differ on that.

Comment: @JeremyKahan its roundup so the answer should be 100.

Comment: So just know the first version of the accepted answer gives 10 when you feed it 10 (the second gives 100)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could take the logarithm of ten and round up the value for getting the value.

```js
function roundup(v) {
    return Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(v)));
}

console.log(roundup(87));   //   100
console.log(roundup(776));  //  1000
console.log(roundup(2333)); // 10000
```

For negative numbers, you might save the sign by taking the result of the check as factor or take a negative one. Then an absolute value is necessary, because logarithm works only with positive numbers.

```js
function roundup(v) {
    return (v >= 0 || -1) * Math.pow(10, 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))));
}

console.log(roundup(87));    //    100
console.log(roundup(-87));   //   -100
console.log(roundup(776));   //   1000
console.log(roundup(-776));  //  -1000
console.log(roundup(2333));  //  10000
console.log(roundup(-2333)); // -10000
```

Comment: `(v >= 0 || -1)` that was my reason to upvote ... and it probably has to be explained to other visitors ...

Comment: I find it interesting that these two implementations disagree on what to do with 1, 10, 100, ... I like the use of just math for the math function. How cool is it that taking the log of 0 gives -infinity and raising 10 to that works?

Answer (score 7):

```
 const roundup = n => 10 ** ("" + n).length
```

Just use the number of characters.

Comment: I wont know the number of characters beforehand.

Comment: @eren555 but you can easily get that by turning the number (`n`) into a string (`"" + n`) and then getting its length

Answer (score 5):

You can check how many digits are in the number and use exponentiation:

```js
const roundup = num => 10 ** String(num).length;
console.log(roundup(87));
console.log(roundup(776));
console.log(roundup(2333));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String#repeat` combined with `Number#toString` in order to achieve that :

```js
const roundUp = number => +('1'+'0'.repeat(number.toString().length));

console.log(roundUp(30));
console.log(roundUp(300));
console.log(roundUp(3000));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
//Math.pow(10,(value+"").length)   


console.log(Math.pow(10,(525+"").length))
console.log(Math.pow(10,(5255+"").length))
```

I came up with another solution that does'nt require a new function to be created